# Activity is destroyed after coming back from camera app

Tags: android, camera, android-lifecycle

I have an activity with a dialog. In the dialog when I click on the ImageView the default camera app launches and when I create the photo and click the tick icon (at least it's a tick icon on my phone) the previous activity is recreated, destroyed and recreated again. This happens about 1 in 10 times.

This is what happens

```
1. Intent opens camera
2. onPause()
3. onSaveInstanceState runs
4. onStop()
5. onDestroy() 
6. Camera app opens, picture is taken and I click tick
7. onStart﹕()
8. onRestoreInstanceState runs
9. onResume()
10. onPause()
11. onSaveInstanceState
12. onStop()
13. onDestroy()
14. onStart﹕()
15. onRestoreInstanceState
```

So even if I save the data I need in onSaveInstanceState (step 3) and it is retrieved in onRestoreInstanceState (step 8), it's lost when the Activity is destroyed (I use a flag to decide if I want to save the data and that flag becomes null when the activity is recreated the second time). I could save everything in SharedPreferences, but still, this is an undesired function I want to correct.

If that matters, here's some code:

**Intent**

```
btn_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
   which_dialog = "complete";
   complete_dialog.dismiss();
   imageFileForCamera_ = getTemporaryDirectory();
   Intent intentPicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   if (imageFileForCamera_ != null) {
      intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFileForCamera_));
   }
startActivityForResult(intentPicture,PICK_FROM_CAMERA_COMPLETE_KITKAT);
```

**onActivityResult:**

```
case PICK_FROM_CAMERA_COMPLETE_KITKAT:
  selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileForCamera_);
  complete_dialog.show();
  (...more code...)
```

**onSaveInstanceState**

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (which_dialog != null && which_dialog.length() > 1) {
       outState.putString("which_dialog", which_dialog);
       outState.putSerializable(INSTANCE_STATE_IMAGE_FILE_FOR_CAMERA, imageFileForCamera_);
    } else {
       Log.i("onSaveInstanceState which_dialog", "which_dialog is null");
    }
}
```

**onRestoreInstanceState**

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("which_dialog")) {
           if (savedInstanceState.getString("which_dialog").equals("complete")) {
               complete_dialog = new CompleteDialog(Activity.this);
               imageFileForCamera_ = (File)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(INSTANCE_STATE_IMAGE_FILE_FOR_CAMERA);
            }
        }
    } else {
         Log.i("onRestoreInstanceState", "savedInstanceState is null");
    }
}
```

Comment: "it's lost when the Activity is destroyed" -- aren't you putting it in the saved instance state `Bundle` in step #11 as well? You should be getting that back in step #15.

Comment: Please see the code attached

Comment: sorry to bother u here.. as i cant send priv message:
did u found a solution for ur 'old' question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565102/android-widget-button-works-only-after-2nd-install-of-app  (u may comment there i would see it)

Answer (score 0):

You are saving `which_dialog` in `onSaveInstanceState()`. You are not restoring `which_dialog` in `onRestoreInstanceState()`. Modify your `onRestoreInstanceState()` to set `which_dialog` based on the value you saved in `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: It looks like it did it. It also looks like the activity is no longer destroyed. Can this be the result of restoring `which_dialog` in `onRestoreInstanceState()`?

Comment: @erdomester: I would not expect that behavior, but I do not know much about your app.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will accept the solution once I made sure it really helped and I am not just "lucky" for not encountering the issue